# pip successfully installed but not running

Tags: python-2.7, module, pip

My computer had problems and I had to reinstall several applications, including Python 2.7.8-64 bit. Since many packages are installed via pip I had to install this latter too. I downloaded pip's source, built it and it apparently installed OK with no error messages in the end of the process. But when I execute it I get the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==8.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2229, in load
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg\pip\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg\pip\vcs\mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg\pip\download.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cgi
  File "C:\Users\fausto\Documents\Programs\Python\cgi.py", line 11, in <module>
    import cgi, string, sys, md5crypt
ImportError: No module named md5crypt
```

That's a total bummer, because pip is essential and I'm stuck with tons of packages that I need but can't install. Any insights on this problem?

Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

PS: I know that pip comes bundled with Python >= 2.7.9, but I wish to keep using 2.7.8 for the time being (for reasons that aren't worth mentioning here and now).

Comment: Looks like your Python installation doesn't have md5crypt. Probably because it relies on some external libraries that you'll need to install before you can install md5crypt.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is try `$ pip freeze` and see if the installed module is there. The only way I can think is that you've installed it globally but you are running inside the `virtualenv` or vice versa.

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ virtualenv env
$ . env/bin/activate

(env)$ pip install <module>
(env)$ pip freeze
<module>==<module version>
```

Here's also link for [pip](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) for Ubuntu and this [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) for Windows

`$ pip freeze` allows you to check for installed modules

Comment: "pip freeze" shows the very same error. Also, I've just found out that the cgi module is not installed, because "import cgi" fails. Is that possible? Isn't cgi one of Python's built-in modules?

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was: a conflict with another package that included its own Python interpreter. Once removed from the path and from the system altogether everything began to miraculously work. Lesson learned.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out.